# Access box.com files for server upload in IOS

Tags: php, ios, file-upload, box-api

I am developing a mobile site using jQuery mob  (IOS integration primarily). there's a password protected page on my site that contains a form enabling the logged in user to upload an image, a pdf file and some text fields to a the server. The image and text fields are not a problem for IOS.

Using IOS, when user clicks file upload button (for the pdf file) the button directs to only images stored on iPhone. I would like the upload button to direct to the list of files in the users box.com account on iPhone. User can then select one of the pdf files there and it then uploads it to the mob websites server, and returns user back to my mobile website.

Can/how do I do this? I have been reading through the box.com API and so far only seeing info for developers creating apps within box.com, I don't want that. I want to keep my mob site separate and just be able to access the files in the users box account.

Comment: How does this relate to php?

Comment: @Paul Dessert 2 My upload script is written in PHP, and I would prefer to keep all server side work if needed to access files in this box app, in php if possible

Comment: @Rhillz Were u able to display file chooser window, could u pls give the helpful link :)